# ios, accessor to get either of two member variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I'm trying to use WKWebView.
Thing is I'll have to support UIWebView as well because there are people with ios < 8.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) WKWebView* wkWebview;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIWebView* uiWebview;
```

Now, it seems I need two versions of function (or branches) everywhere.. 
Look at the following function.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
- (void)loadWebview {

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.mUrlString];
    NSURLRequest* requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    if([self.isUseWKWebview]) {
        [self.wkWebview loadRequest:requestObj];
    } else {
        [self.uiWebview loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way would be to bypass all type checking

```
- (id)currentWebview {
    if ([self.isUseWKWebview]) {
       return self.wkWebview;
    else {
       return self.uiWebview;
    }
}
```

I would, however, prefer to declare a protocol with the methods that are common to both classes.

```
@protocol AnyWebviewType {
   - (void)commonLoadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)requestObj;
}
```

Then we need a category on each class

```
@interface UIWebview (AnyWebviewType) : AnyWebviewType 

@end

@interface WKWebView (AnyWebviewType) : AnyWebviewType 

@end
```

Now the currentWebview method declaration becomes

```
- (id<AnyWebviewType>)currentWebview;
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: looks promising! would it be a bad idea to define `- (void) loadRequest` to shadow the original function? instead of `commonLoadRequest`

Comment: Yes - never define a method in a category that has the same name as an existing method in the class the category is defined on. It is undefined which method will get called runtime. You can override methods from the super class inside a category.